# What is difference between eclipse compare API?

Tags: java, eclipse, compare, emf

I have to create own eclipse compare editor, so I can see difference between models as I want.
(Need to create customize compare editor UI.)
While surfing on internet I found two different API.
**org.eclipse.emf.compare** and **org.eclipse.compare**.

What is difference between these two API?
Which should I use to create own compare editor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`org.eclipse.compare` is part of core Eclipse and provides a general API for comparing text and other files.

`org.eclipse.emf.compare` is part of the Eclipse Modelling Framework (EMF). I am not familiar with this but presumably it provides an API for comparing EMF models.